# Regex match trailing space inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using JavaScript and I want to match trailing space inside quotes **('\' inside here \'')**, afterwards I will replace the match with empty string.

Example: `'  abc   cde     '` should be  `'  abc   cde'`

Now I have this which is working without quotes: `[^\S]+$`

Any ideas ?

---

UPDATE:

My question was maybe not clear enough, I have something like this `'\'HALO    \''` what I want is to remove the trailing spaces inside those escaped quotes.

Comment: Something like `s.replace(/'[^']+'/g, function(x) {return x.replace(/\s+$/, '');})`. To support escape sequences, the first regex should be `/'[^\\']*(?:\\[^][^\\']*)*'/g`

Comment: @DragandDrop no it is not a duplicate, because I want to remove the space at the and inside of quotes, example '\' HELLO     \'' → '\'  HELLO\''

Comment: Not the exact duplicate especialy after question edit. But still when you look at the answer here and the answer on the duplicate you can replace the `~` by `\s` and have the exact same regex. And after the edit that invalidate the answer you got. There is only a `'` difference

Comment: @DragandDrop but still in my original question before the edit you can see that I was very close (`[^\S]+$`), if i add that `'` like this `[^\S]+'$` I have the solution. The problem is that it did not come to my mind that in combination with replace I can add back the `'` and have my solution to the problem. Anyway in my opinion my question has nothing to do with the already asked question linked above.

Comment: Why downvote? It's a legit question. If it's duplicate mark it as such. He also provided what he tried, maybe he is just not good with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "'   abc  def   '";
console.log(str.replace(/\s+'$/, "'"));

str = "'   abc  def'";
console.log(str.replace(/\s+'$/, "'"));
```

https://jsbin.com/rowomah/edit?js,console

https://regex101.com/r/3BXlhB/2

Answer (score 1):

```
'  abc   cde     '.replace(/(\s)*$/, '')
```

Does this work for all your cases?

Look here on how it works:
[regex visualization](https://regexper.com/#%2F(%5Cs)*%24%2F)

It searches 0 to multiple occurrences of space on end of string and replaces it with an empty string.

NOTE: If you need it to work with an actual ' on the end use this:

```
'\'  abc   cde     \''.replace(/(\s)*'$/, '\'')
```

this one expects an ' to be in the end and then replaces all spaces and ' with only '

If you have the need to fix strings that might or might not have ' in the end, use both .replace() in succession you should have both cases covered as they don't overlap ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, but you have a double negated pattern `[^...]` with `\S`.

You can actually use this pattern:

```
\s+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/QaoYVZ/2/)**

Code

```
const regex = /\s+$/gm;
const str = `  abc   cde     `;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: I like how you used +, I used * and it's unnecessary. This should be the accepted answer since it's shortest and uses m global flag as well (altho from his example it's not obvious if it's needed.